# How to set height and width in do_shortcodein wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

```
echo do_shortcode('[soundcloud_ultimate track=http://soundcloud.com/samples]');
```

How to set height and width in above shortcode in wordpress? is it possible to change in do_shortcode function?

Comment: `do_shortcode` is a built in function of WordPress. This function will render a shortcode passed to it. The shortcode being called here is the `soundcloud_ultimate` shortcode. The shortcode only supports the `track` and the `autoplay` attributes. If you want to change the width and height of the rendered player, try using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

WP Shortcodes are place holders for HTML code generators, usually provided by a plugin.

As the HTML is generated by the plugin only editing the plugin will allow you to add missing functionality.

If you need elaboration on this then you will need to edit your question to show the code you're working on.